# Getting express to ignore slashes in route parameters

Tags: node.js, express

My node.js code uses encodeURIComponent to encode URI parameters that sometimes contain slashes. In my dev environment these URIs route correctly but they fail in production. (I deploy to production from github using git.)

I verified I'm running the same versions of node.js (v11.6.0) and express (4.16.4) in dev and prod. I also tested using the same data and the same browser (Chrome) in both environments.

The route has 3 parameters:

```
router.get('/resetpw/:username/:schoolCode/:school', function(req, res) {
```

Here is sample data with encoded slashes (%2F) in both username and school:

```
resetpw/dumb%2Fhappy%40gmail.com/afal3043/Academy%20for%20Advanced%2FCreative%20Learning
```

This routes correctly in dev and the proper page is rendered.
On production, it gets: `The requested URL /resetpw/dumb/happy@gmail.com/afal3043/Academy for Advanced/Creative Learning was not found on this server.`
I get the same result when there is a slash in only one parameter.

My questions:

1. Is this a bug in the production environment? ( My understanding is that routing should occur before the parameters are decoded, as it does in the Dev environment. ) **Update**: This link https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html references an Express Route Tester (http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/). This tester indicates "the path matches the route". So this answers the first question; it indicates the behavior in the dev environment (routing before decoding parameters) is the intended behavior and it is not working correctly in the prod environment.
2. Is there some server or express configuration that could explain the difference in behavior?
3. Is there some other way to encode slashes in parameters so they wouldn't confuse the express router? **Update**: I changed my code to put the parameters in a query string, e.g.

```
resetpw?username=paul%40abc123.com&schoolCode=abc123&school=ABC%20%2Fschool
```

I then removed the parameters from the route:

```
router.get('/resetpw', function(req, res) {
```

This works in both the dev and prod environment. This solves my problem but I still don't know why the first technique worked in dev but not in prod.

Comment: I have your exact problem, in production it sees the url without encoding so it jumps inside another route, in local it works perfectly, how you solved this problem?

Comment: I solved it as mentioned in the update I added to question 3. Instead of relying on Express route parameters (that were not interpreted correctly in production), I put the 3 parameters into a query string.

Comment: Thank you i solved my issue by changing the settings of Nginx that was the problem

Comment: Interesting... I wasn't using Nginx so that solution wouldn't have worked for me.

Comment: @d0xzen could you please mention what settings to nginx that you made. If you still recall. I know it might have been some time.